# VBA Loop Code for every 10000 rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VB code to generate a CSV file from Excel WorkBook.

My data is quite big and I would like the code start chunking at every 10000 rows.

I basically want it to loop at every 10000 rows.

Please help.

```
 Sub PriceList()
    Set objworksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Price List")

    output_path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")

    Set myfileFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    output_file_name = "Sales Price List" & ".txt"

    Set myts = myfileFSO.CreateTextFile(output_path & "\" & output_file_name)


    introw = 1
    Count = 0
    Do Until objworksheet.Cells(introw, 1).Value = ""
        Count = Count + 1
        introw = introw + 1
        Loop


    For i = 4 To Count

    If i = 4 Then

    myts.write "E;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & ";" _
    & objworksheet.Cells(i, 3).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 4).Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
    "L;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 5).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 6).Value & ";" _
    & objworksheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 8).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 9).Value _
    & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 10).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 11).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 12).Value _
    & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 13).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 14).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 15) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)

    End If

    If i > 4 Then

    If objworksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = objworksheet.Cells((i - 1), 2).Value Then

    myts.write "L;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 5).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 6).Value _
    & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 8).Value & ";" _
    & objworksheet.Cells(i, 9).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 10).Value & ";" _
    & objworksheet.Cells(i, 11).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 12).Value & ";" _
    & objworksheet.Cells(i, 13).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 14).Value & objworksheet.Cells(i, 15) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)

    Else

    myts.write "E;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & ";" _
    & objworksheet.Cells(i, 3).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 4).Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
    "L;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 5).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 6).Value & ";" _
    & objworksheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 8).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 9).Value _
    & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 10).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 11).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 12).Value _
    & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 13).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 14).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 15) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)


    End If

    End If


    Next

     MsgBox "Done."






End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with "start chunking"?

Comment: I meant the code should do the process for every 1000 rows.

Comment: Generate one file each 1000 rows?

Comment: Yes sir. If that is possible. Or in the same file start from the top and continue for every 10000 rows.

Comment: That cell-by-cell access is going to be super-slow: your code will run much faster if you read all the data into a 2-D array and access it from there.

Comment: If I understand the logic behind this, you output the headers which are in row 4, then check if each row value in column B is equal to the previous one and depending on that, output some columns or others. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cell-by-cell access is going to be super-slow: your code will run much faster if you read all the data into a 2-D array and access it from there.

**EDIT** update to chunk output

```
Sub PriceList()
    Const CHUNK_SIZE As Long = 100
    Dim data, lr As Long, i As Long, repeat As Boolean
    Dim output_path As String, myfileFSO, myts
    Dim ws As Worksheet, chunkNumber As Long

    '** placeholder in output path for chunk number
    output_path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & _
                                              "\blah\Sales Price List-{chunk}.txt"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Price List")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        data = .Range(.Range("A4"), .Cells(lr, 15)).Value
    End With

    chunkNumber = 1
    Set myts = OutputFile(output_path, chunkNumber)

    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)

        'repeat row ?
        repeat = False 'default
        If i > 1 Then repeat = (data(i, 2) = data((i - 1), 2))

        If Not repeat Then
            myts.write Join(Array("E", data(i, 1), data(i, 2), data(i, 3), data(i, 4)), ";") & vbCrLf
        End If

        myts.write Join(Array("L", data(i, 5), data(i, 6), data(i, 7), data(i, 8), _
                                    data(i, 9), data(i, 10), data(i, 11), data(i, 12), _
                                    data(i, 13), data(i, 14), data(i, 15)), ";") & vbCrLf

        If i Mod CHUNK_SIZE = 0 Then
            myts.Close
            chunkNumber = chunkNumber + 1
            Set myts = OutputFile(output_path, chunkNumber)
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

Function OutputFile(fPath As String, chunkNumber As Long)
    Set OutputFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). _
                       CreateTextFile(Replace(fPath, "{chunk}", chunkNumber))
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. But how do I break this for every 10000 rows?